# Multiple Line charts in R using ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, line

This is my data . I want to create multiple line charts for the different variables . The long form of the data is being created using "melt" from "reshape2" package .

```
The current code I am using is :

ggplot(data = agg_melt_p, aes(x=Cat, y=value)) + geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
```

This gives me the following error: `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

Data:

```
Cat <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

variable <- c("IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p","IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p")

value <- c(21,17,16,210,20,17,15,189,20,17,15,188,19,17,15,188,20,17,15,194)

agg_melt_p <- data.frame(cat, variable, value)
```

Comment: try `group = variable` in the geom line aes?

Comment: Your code works, given the data snapshot you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both your code, using `colour=variable`, and [Scientist_jake's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317295/multiple-line-charts-in-r-using-ggplot2-package#comment83620366_48317295) to use `group = variable`, works for me. As follows,

```
agg_melt_p <- data.frame(cat = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                  1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
              variable = c("IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p",
                 "IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p","IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p",
                 "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p",
                 "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p",
                 "IL_5_Flag_p"),
              value = c(21, 17, 16, 210, 20, 17, 15, 189, 20, 17,
                       15, 188, 19, 17, 15, 188, 20, 17, 15, 194))

# install.packages(c("ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = agg_melt_p, aes(x = cat, y = value)) + 
       geom_line(aes(colour = variable))
```

[image: colour = variable]

```
ggplot(data = agg_melt_p, aes(x = cat, y=value)) +  
      geom_line(aes(group = variable))
```

[image: group = variable]

Comment: This works for me ! Thanks ! Also can you tell how to scale the values I am using ?  I am appending this line chart with a 100% Stacked bar chart with the same X axis as Category .

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please ask any new questions an a _new question_.